# Navmesh baking for multiple levels

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am faced with a problem for which I think there are no solutions but I am looking for confirmation.

I have this set of floor planes:

[image: one floor over another]

When I bake them I get this navmesh as a result:

[image: navmesh]

The upper floor does not allow the navmesh to be created on the area below.

Do you know any workarounds or is it impossible?

Comment: Its not impossible for a navmesh generation system to handle this case. Its quite common. Whether or not the option is available in Unity's navmesh baker, I don't remember.

Comment: Hi Draco18s, thanks for your reply.
As much as it may be a common problem I can't find anything that comes close to the answer. I searched the net and in the forums but no questions like mine. I also looked in the Unity help but in the Navigation tab there doesn't seem to be any information about it.

Comment: If you had any more information in mind, I would be grateful.

Comment: Solved, it was Agent Height too high.
Thank you.